# Remove Docker GPG Key

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, docker

recently I want to install Docker in my kali machine. I install the wrong (Ubuntu) version in my Kali.

I did a `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg`

So if I want to `apt-get update` it give me a message

```
$ sudo apt-get update                                                                             1 ⨯
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                          
Hit:3 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                   
Hit:4 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu kali-rolling InRelease                                  
Err:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu kali-rolling Release                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:21b4:3000:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
Hit:7 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                             
Hit:9 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease            
Hit:8 https://mirror.anigil.com/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I want to remove the Docker GPG Key. How do I do that? Thank you before :D

Note: I follow this tutorial to install docker before I install the right version

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Kali Linux isn't a normal operating system. It is a tool designed for experts and if you don't know the answers to basic support question, you really shouldn't be using Kali Linux since it will only make your life harder. Use any GNU/Linux and you can do everything you can do on Kali Linux.  https://www.kali.org/docs//introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not on gpg keys, it is the ppa you added— resulting on those error. To get rid of the problem, you need to remove the ppa.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo apt update
```

Provided you have install the right version, one also can remove it manually from the file, thus diminish the possibility of any error.

```
sudo find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec grep -i 'download.docker.com' {} \; -print
```

Will give you file containing `download.docker.com`, to which you can remove the problematic line from said file.

Comment: Right! I follow your instruction. And it totally works just fine. Thank you for helping me :D